Refit is downloading html data instead of image (png) from dropbox image url
I have implemented refit from here and it is working for any png image on any site, but for dropbox, when I download from url it gives html text instead of encoded png text
[Get("/{url}")]
public Task<string> DownloadPhoto_s(string url);

This is my string downloading code
public static string get_image_from_dropbox(string url)
{

    var client234 = RestService.For<refit_interface_file>("https://www.dropbox.com");
    var client567 = client234.DownloadPhoto_s(url.Replace("https://www.dropbox.com/", ""));
    return client567.Result;
}


get_image_from_dropbox("https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/pdbpoz9f1ejuc6ams009w/download.png?rlkey=ujlyhgqggocvcaueo9fg7wstg&raw=1");
//here I get html string with many <script> tags. Is it not possible for downloading image from dropbox?

Thanks in advance
